# cell.edit doesn't work (Tabulator Node.js)

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I got a strange problem: method "cell.edit()" doesn't work (an error *"Uncaught TypeError: e.column.modules.edit is undefined"*), however at the same time all other methods works perfectly (e.g. cell.getField(); cell.getValue()).
Why could this happen?

My code:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#grid1", {
        data:dannyje_iz_json, //assign data to table
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        rowContextMenu: rowMenu, //add context menu to rows
        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
            {title:"ID", field:"id"},
            {title:"Имя", field:"name", cellDblClick:function(e, cell){
                cell.edit(true); //works fine if change this to alert(cell.getField()); alert(cell.getValue());
                //now it leads to the error Uncaught TypeError: e.column.modules.edit is undefined
            }},
            {title:"Возраст", field:"age"},
        ],
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have no editor defined on your column so it is not possible to call edit on it. Also there is no point calling edit in the double click event, it will be trigged on click as standard.

So yuo would be looking at something like this for the column definition:

```js
{title:"Имя", field:"name", editor:"input"},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, of course, the way you suggested works fine, but i just wanted to make selection by one click and editing by double click (something like in Google Spreadsheets, MS Excel). 
Section "Documentation -> Component Objects -> Cell Component" of you respectable site says "If you want to ignore the editable property of the column definition and force the edit, you can pass an optional value of true to the function
cell.edit(true);"
That's why i thought it will works even without an editor...